# Suspend Bitlocker if Bitlocker Encryption is enabled

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I have a powershell script which updates the BIOS from our Computers.

I would like to supend the bitlocker with this command

"Suspend-BitLocker -MountPoint C: -RebootCount 1"

**But only if Bitlocker is enabled.**

Is there a chance to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `if ((Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint "C:").ProtectionStatus -eq "On") { ... }`. Potentially simpler is to just slap on `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, if (as I suspect) this command will do nothing bad if BitLocker is not enabled at all.

Comment: Bit locker commands require elevated privilege so you might also want to check for that if you take @JeroenMostert 's suggestion.

Comment: When i use the command "Suspend-BitLocker -MountPoint C: -RebootCount 1" i get this Notification after the Reboot 
"Bitlocker could not be activated"